# Airflow PubSubPullSensor/Operator: How to can we acknowledge a gcp PubSub Message by downstream tasks when "ack_messages" flag is set to False

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to implement [PubSubPullSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/pubsub/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.pubsub.PubSubPullSensor.execute) and [PubSubPullOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/pubsub/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.pubsub.PubSubPullOperator) to process message from a GCP PubSub Topic and need to acknowledge the message only if downstream task is able to successfully handle that message . However i am unable to find any good examples to acknowledge each message separately from downstream tasks, are there any Operators Built-in that i can leverage or i should implement using [PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/acknowledge) APIs using a PythonOperator task?.

The documentation says

> If ack_messages is set to True, messages will be immediately acknowledged before being returned, otherwise, downstream tasks will be responsible for acknowledging them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little bit of research this is how i did it. Manual acknowledgement can be achieved by providing a callback method to [PullSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/pubsub/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.pubsub.PubSubPullSensor.execute) or [PullOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/pubsub/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.pubsub.PubSubPullOperator) and handle that acknowledge logic inside the callback method by leveraging `PubSubHook().acknowledge` method. A sample example using PullOperator is given below. While working on this solution i have faced some issues with the arguments passed to [PubSubHook().acknowledge](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/pubsub/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.pubsub.PubSubHook.acknowledge) method, please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248158/call-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-metadata-error-for-airflow-pubsu) for more details.

```
from __future__ import annotations
import os
from datetime import datetime
import base64
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
import json
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.pubsub import (
    PubSubCreateSubscriptionOperator,
    PubSubPullOperator,
)
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.pubsub import PubSubPullSensor
from  airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.pubsub import PubSubHook,Retry


ENV_ID = "Dev" #os.environ.get("SYSTEM_TESTS_ENV_ID")
PROJECT_ID = "abcdef" #os.environ.get("SYSTEM_TESTS_GCP_PROJECT", "your-project-id")
DAG_ID = "DataPullDag_1"
TOPIC_ID = "alert_topic_jp" #f"topic-{DAG_ID}-{ENV_ID}"
SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION="alert_subscription_jp"

def print_ack_messages(pulled_messages, context):
    retryObj = Retry(initial=10, maximum=10, multiplier=1.0, deadline=600)
    for idx,m in enumerate(pulled_messages):
      data = m.message.data.decode('utf-8')
      print(f'################{data}')     
      data_json_dict = json.loads(data)     
      print(f"AckID: { m.ack_id }, incident_id: { data_json_dict['incident']['incident_id'] }"
       f"scoping_project_id: { data_json_dict['incident']['scoping_project_id'] } "
       f"resource_name: { data_json_dict['incident']['resource_name'] } "
       f"summary: { data_json_dict['incident']['summary'] } ")
       
      ack_id_list = [m.ack_id]
      print(type(ack_id_list))
      #remove this if condition for acknowledging all the messages
      if idx == 0:
        PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list, retry=retryObj, timeout=10)
        print(f"Successfully acknowldeged incident_id: { data_json_dict['incident']['incident_id'] }")


with DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval='@once',  # Override to match your needs
    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
# [START howto_operator_gcp_pubsub_create_subscription]
  subscribe_task = PubSubCreateSubscriptionOperator(
  task_id="subscribe_task", project_id=PROJECT_ID, topic=TOPIC_ID,subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION
  )
  
  subscription = subscribe_task.output

  pull_messages_operator = PubSubPullOperator(
    task_id="pull_messages_operator",
    ack_messages=False,
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,       
    messages_callback=print_ack_messages,
    subscription=subscription,
    max_messages=50,
  )
  (
    subscribe_task         
    >> pull_messages_operator    
    
  )
```