# __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metadata' error for Airflow PubSubHook acknowledge method

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to manually acknowledge each PubSub messages in the Python call back method for [PubSubPull](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/pubsub/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.pubsub.PubSubPullOperator) Operator. I have provided the arguments as per the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/pubsub/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.pubsub.PubSubHook.acknowledge). However when i am getting errors related to optional "metadata" argument

**Scenario 1 - when metadata=[]**: Getting error -> **call**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metadata'

```
PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list, retry=Retry , timeout=10,metadata=[])

**Traceback:**
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/pubsub.py", line 785, in execute
    ret = handle_messages(pulled_messages, context)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/snow_ticket_creator_1.py", line 70, in print_messages
    PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list, retry=Retry , timeout=10)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 457, in inner_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/pubsub.py", line 561, in acknowledge
    subscriber.acknowledge(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/pubsub_v1/services/subscriber/client.py", line 1270, in acknowledge
    rpc(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metadata'
```

**Scenario 2 - when metadata = None**: Getting error message TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list, retry=Retry , timeout=10,metadata=None)

File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/pubsub.py", line 785, in execute
    ret = handle_messages(pulled_messages, context)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/snow_ticket_creator_1.py", line 70, in print_messages
    PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list, retry=Retry , timeout=10,metadata=None)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 457, in inner_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/pubsub.py", line 561, in acknowledge
    subscriber.acknowledge(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/pubsub_v1/services/subscriber/client.py", line 1263, in acknowledge
    metadata = tuple(metadata) + (
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

**Scenario 3 - when metadata is omitted: Getting error -> **call**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metadata'

```
PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list, retry=Retry , timeout=10)

Traceback: Same as Scenario 1
```

**Composer Version composer-1.19.12
Airflow Version -airflow-2.3.3**

Complete Code:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import os
from datetime import datetime
import base64
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
import json
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.pubsub import (
    PubSubCreateSubscriptionOperator,
    PubSubPullOperator,
)
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.pubsub import PubSubPullSensor
from  airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.pubsub import PubSubHook,Retry
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

ENV_ID = "Dev" #os.environ.get("SYSTEM_TESTS_ENV_ID")
PROJECT_ID = "abcdef" #os.environ.get("SYSTEM_TESTS_GCP_PROJECT", "your-project-id")
DAG_ID = "DataPullDag_1"
TOPIC_ID = "alert_topic_jp" #f"topic-{DAG_ID}-{ENV_ID}"
SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION="alert_subscription_jp"

def print_ack_messages(pulled_messages, context):
    for idx,m in enumerate(pulled_messages):
      data = m.message.data.decode('utf-8')
      print(f'################----------{data}')     
      data_json_dict = json.loads(data)     
      print(f"AckID: { m.ack_id }, incident_id: { data_json_dict['incident']['incident_id'] }"
       f"scoping_project_id: { data_json_dict['incident']['scoping_project_id'] } "
       f"resource_name: { data_json_dict['incident']['resource_name'] } "
       f"summary: { data_json_dict['incident']['summary'] } ")
       #acknowldege message
      ack_id_list = [m.ack_id]
      print(type(ack_id_list))
      if idx == 0:
        PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list, retry=Retry , timeout=10)
        print(f"Successfully acknowldeged incident_id: { data_json_dict['incident']['incident_id'] }")


with DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval='@once',  # Override to match your needs
    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
# [START howto_operator_gcp_pubsub_create_subscription]
  subscribe_task = PubSubCreateSubscriptionOperator(
  task_id="subscribe_task", project_id=PROJECT_ID, topic=TOPIC_ID,subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION
  )
  
  subscription = subscribe_task.output

  pull_messages_operator = PubSubPullOperator(
    task_id="pull_messages_operator",
    ack_messages=False,
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,       
    messages_callback=print_ack_messages,
    subscription=subscription,
    max_messages=50,
  )
  (
    subscribe_task         
    >> pull_messages_operator    
    
  )
```

Comment: This looks like a bug... Under the hood the Hook is calling `google.cloud.pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient` - have you tried making the exact subscriber request using `google-cloud-pubsub` library? Do you get the same error?

Comment: I have tried with ack_messages=True and it is working. Also it is going through the same acknowledge method internally. So i too think its a bug.

Comment: I looked bit deep into the PullOperator "ack_messages=True"  stacktrace and i could see that only these three options the are used in that method , project_id, subscription, pulled_messages. So i have tried with these and it worked. I have then found out the exact argument that caused the issue , it was "retry=Retry", still think it as a bug though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did bit more experimenting into the actual source code for PullOperator (if we provide "ack_messages=True" in the PullOperator itself, it will acknowledge all the pulled messages by calling `hook.acknowledge(project_id=self.project_id,subscription=self.subscription,messages=pulled_messages,)` ) and found out that the retry object in my acknowledge call was creating the issue. So instead of `PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list, retry=Retry , timeout=10)` i have dropped retry object and used `PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list,  timeout=10)` and it worked!!!.

However as per the documentation [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/pubsub/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.pubsub.PubSubHook.acknowledge), retry object has a purpose,

> retry object used to retry requests. If None is specified, requests will not be retried.

**Update 31/10/2022**

This was due to a mistake in the code, instead of Retry object i was using Retry class. Thank you for pointing this out [Taragolis](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/27384#issuecomment-1297030268) (airflow collaborator).

In the above code if we replace Retry class with retry object it will work, as shown below

```
retryObj= Retry(initial=10, maximum=10, multiplier=1.0, deadline=600)
PubSubHook().acknowledge(subscription=SNOW_SUBSCRIPTION,project_id=PROJECT_ID, ack_ids=ack_id_list, retry=retryObj, timeout=10)
```